# Insertion sort starting from end of vector

Tags: c++, sorting, c++11

I'm trying to do an insertion sort but in the opposite order of normal (start from the second to last element, not the second element). The vector should be converted to ascending order.

Here's what I have but it's not working (out of bounds error):

```
void sort(vector<double> &a) {
    for (int n = a.size() - 2; n >= 0; --n) {
        double aTemp = a.at(n);
        int i = n+1;
        while (i < a.size() - 1 && aTemp < a.at(i)) {
            a[i] = a[i + 1];
            ++i;
        }
        a[i+1] = aTemp;
    }
}

int main() {
    vector<double> a = {3, 2, 5, 8, 1, 9};
    sort(a);
    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); ++i) {
        cout << a[i] << ' ';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why not just do it normally and reverse vector at the end? Unless I understood it wrong?

Comment: Did you know inside the `std` namespace there is a `sort` function: `std::sort`, and you've got both `sort` and `std::sort` visible under the name `sort` by saying `using namespace std`?

Comment: The while loop terminates when `i == a.size() - 1`, then you try to set `a[i+1]`. Of course it's out of bounds.

Comment: `std::reverse` and then `std::sort`, that does an intelligent sorting.

Comment: you can use `std::vector::rbegin()` to get a `RandomAccessIterator` to the reversed vector, and proceed as if you were inserting from the start.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you do know about the STL sort function and are just experimenting with Insertion Sort.
Your logic for the most part is correct. The only problem I found was that you were leaving the `a[n]` 'hole' unfilled and in the worst case adding items in the `a[a.size()]`.

```
int i = n;
while (i <  a.size() - 1 && aTemp > a.at(i+1)) {
    a[i] = a[i + 1];
    ++i;
}
a[i] = aTemp;
```

Replacing with this [solved](http://cpp.sh/6knsv) the problem.